# Find all Tables where a specific alias of a field name (column) has been used on a Data Entry Form

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database on `SQL Server 2014` and I need to find out all tables on that database which contain a specific column name (based on an alias used on an Entry Form).

**Let me elaborate further:**

There is a screen (end-user interface) with several fields and this form is used for data entry. All data submitted from this form is registered in a SQL Server Database.

Let us assume one of the fields (used for entering Country of Residence) is registered into a SQL Table in a specific column called "CtyRes". For end-user clarity, the field is displayed as "Country of Residence" on the Form.

**Here is my problem:**

If I don't know that this field on the Entry Form is linked to the "CtyRes" column of, say, Table T1, how can I use the wordings "Country Of Residence" in `T-SQL` to look for the relevant Table name and Column name used in the database?

I know I can do the following, in cases where I know the Column name and I am looking for the Table Name concerned:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
              FROM syscolumns 
              WHERE name like '%ctyres%' )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I really don't follow what you are asking here. I feel like you need to give real examples here, not a long description with no sample data or expected results.

Comment: If you do not know that some column is linked to some field of the form, then database also does not know it, because it is your **application** code. Your **application** should know the column used in specific place and issue a `select` statement to the database to find something stored inside the database based on this column name. But the overall problem sounds strange, because different tables can have the same column with different meaning

Comment: Can you do test uses of the platform? If so, open the profiler and track the changes done.